# How to know if microphone or any hardware is accessed by any other app through logs or anything else

Tags: android

Hello I want to develop an app in which I want a functionality that if camera or microphone is accessed by an app so I will capture that event and create logs or if there are any logs available in android system by which I can see the usage of these components by apps.

Comment: "I want to develop an app in which I want a functionality that if camera or microphone is accessed by an app so I will capture that event and create logs" -- that's not generally possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, for obvious privacy and security reasons. "if there are any logs available in android system by which I can see the usage of these components by apps" -- there may be enough information in LogCat for you to determine that these are being used. However, your app does not have rights to view LogCat data coming from other apps, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: ok @CommonsWare brother thanks for your guidance